# Is my salary halal if I have not get work or assignment for a long duration?

Tags: quran, fiqh, work

Is it legal per Islam or is there any indication in the qur'an to take a salary when someone in a virtual bench person working in an IT company? Not working because he or she did not get work or assignment from the employer during a virtual bench period (2 months).

Comment: @Medi1Saif I have got a job in a company & am on a bench that means I did not get an assignment or work to do but at the same time I can't go the other company & ask for a work.Here I'm giving my time.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.